# Moving WCF service to Azure VM

Tags: wcf, iis, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a WCF service service that runs good while hosted in local IIS, but gives the following exception when hosted in an Azure VM IIS :

```
DispatchOperation requires Invoker. 
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: DispatchOperation requires Invoker
```

StackTrace :

```
[InvalidOperationException: DispatchOperation requires Invoker.]
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime..ctor(DispatchOperation operation, ImmutableDispatchRuntime parent) +17276262
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime..ctor(DispatchRuntime dispatch) +824
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchRuntime.GetRuntimeCore() +114
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpened() +520
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +766
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +260
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +742
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +126
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +901

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/PidPlusService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: DispatchOperation requires Invoker..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +650220
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +210733
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +282
```

I have the svc file, web.config file and the dlls that are there in the service. The service project is a class library project and is part of a solution that generates the dlls.
Is there something that needs to be changed in code for hosting in Azure? Or is it a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure the Virtual Machine to support WCF, just as you did your local on-premise IIS machine.  Insure that [these settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675150%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are configured on your VM in Azure.

Additionally, you may need to enable in Windows Features 'WCF Http Activation' (.NET Framework 3.5).  If you're targeting .NET Framework 4.5, then make sure 'WCF Services' (.NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services) is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for replying late, but i am still facing the issue. I have enabled every required feature/role through server manager, since i am using WS2012.